# Which packages provide the pictured gnome-panel applets?

Tags: 12.04, gnome-panel, gnome-classic, source

Which source packages contain the source code of the indicated applets?

If the answer is a catch all source package like "gnome-applets", what is name and location of the individual applets within the source package?

Note: I am using 12.04.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the applets is provided by the packages `gnome-panel` and `gnome-panel-data`

```
apt-get source gnome-panel-data
```

The exception is applet 2.

Panel 1:

This is the Menu Bar (custom menu) - the code is in the folder `gnome-panel-3.4.1/applets/wncklet`

Source files: window-menu*

Panel 2:

This is provided by the package `indicator-applet-complete`

Panel 3:

This is the window list - the code is in the folder `gnome-panel-3.4.1/applets/wncklet`

Source files: window-list*

Panel 4:

This is the workspace switcher - the code is in the folder `gnome-panel-3.4.1/applets/wncklet`

Source files: workspace-switcher*

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was after. So 1, 3, and 4 are all provided by /usr/lib/gnome-panel/4.0/libwnck-applet.so? That explains why I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

These are most likely in the 'gnome-panel' package. #2 could also be a combination of 'indicator-applet' (or its clones, 'indicator-applet-*') and 'indicator-session'.